# ListBox with Rounded Corners (Windows Store App)

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-store-apps, styles

I have a `ListBox` inside a `Flyout`. Is there any way of making my `ListBox` corners rounded? I have searched and I couldn't find anything. Is there any style/`Xaml` template you recommend?

This is my code:

```
    <Flyout>
        <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
          <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
             <Setter Property="Margin" Value="30,30,0,0"/>
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
             <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
             <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
             <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="300"/>
             <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200"/>
           </Style>
        </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>


        <ListBox x:Name="AllItemsView" Width="200" Height="auto" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Background="White" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="AllItemsView_SelectionChanged">
           <ListBox.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="Border">

                 <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20,20,20,20"/>
                 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlueViolet"/>
                 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="7"/>
                 <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
               </Style>

            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
               <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
               </Style>

          </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>

               <Grid Width="200" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="colorGrid">
               <Grid.Background>
                   <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ItemType, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ItemTypeToColorConverter1}}" />


               </Grid.Background>
               <StackPanel x:Name="StackItem">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemTitle}" FontWeight="{Binding ItemType, Converter={StaticResource itemTypeToBoldConverter1}}" Margin="{Binding ItemType, Converter={StaticResource itemTypeToMarginConverter1}}" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemPage}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
               </StackPanel>

               </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>

          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

      </ListBox>

 </Flyout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set CornerRadius for the ListBox, you can do the same but in Resources instead

```
 <ListBox ...>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    <!--...-->
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my ListBox is inside a Flyout (I just updated my question). When I add your code, the border will be rounded but with a certain margin, which is not good looking even if I make the border Transparent.

Comment: I edited and provided a new code are you talking about this one?

Comment: I tried your <ListBox.Resources> and it didn't work. Please check my code!